# Options for creating a new iOS app with a subset of features

Tags: ios, xcode

Say I have an iOS app called "Cats" which has a tab bar with 5 options. I need to create a new app that will just be one of these tabs ("Breeds" for example) as its own app. I'd like to leverage the backend functionality of the existing app instead of building an entirely new networking layer, etc. Also, I don't want to have to update the "Breeds" section in both apps going forward. Can I just create a new Target and submit that as its own app? If so, how would I run code specific to the new app, i.e.:

```
if (newApp) {
    //just show the one screen
} else {
    //build all five tabs
}
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: The answer depends on how your architected your primary app. If you built it with a common networking layer, and each tab managed by a separate view controller, it could be as simple as adding additional targets to your project that build your "subset" apps. (I'm not sure whether Apple would allow this or not however.)

Comment: It’s all about architecture but SPM makes this easy if you have good code.